# Nextjs custom server causes material-ui to be static

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, koa

I'm currently developing a NodeJS application with Koa, React, [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/), and NextJS.

I know that there are examples of using a server rendering framework with Material-UI.  However, those examples assume that you're running NextJS' default server (`next <whatever command>`).  In my case, I'm doing a custom NextJS server.

I'm currently trying to implement [Tab](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/) functionality and I'm noticing two problems:

1) When NextJS' development flag is set to true, nothing is rendered on the browser.
2) If I build a production version, I can generate content.  However, I can't interact with the GUI.

When using NextJS' default server, the Tab example code works fine.

I have a feeling that I did something wrong with the configuration of NextJS and Material-UI, but can't quite pinpoint where I went wrong.

Here an [example repository](https://github.com/jsmwoolf/material-ui-nextjs-custom-server) that I created to demonstrate this problem.  Most of the code is just copy past from [Material-UI's NextJS repository](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs).

Comment: If you haven't ever resolved this issue and by some chance is looking at this comment, try running your app in production mode. It somehow solved the issue and I don't even know how and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

you are using koa routing and next.js file system routing same time in your application it would be good if you can disable one of them.

To  disable next.js file system routing paste below code in next.config.js

useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false

To solve your Material-UI static issue goto your server.js file  and change your 
route from

await ctx.render('about')
to 
await ctx.render('/about')

this will solve your problem

Comment: This didn't solve my issue... I ended up trying running my app in production mode and it somehow fixes itself